# Get ObjectID in mongolite R library

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I can successfully retrieve data from my mongoDB instance but need to re-use the objectID for a depending query.

The following code seems to get my entire object but NOT the id. What am I missing?

```
# Perform a query and retrieve data
mongoOBj <- m$find('{"em": "test@test.com"}')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/mongolite.pdf) you see that the `find` method takes a `field` argument, where you specify the fields you want:

```
find(query = ’{}’, fields = ’{"_id" : 0}’, sort = ’{}’, skip = 0, limit = 0, handler = NULL, pagesize = NULL)
```

So in your case it will be something like

```
mongoOBj <- m$find(query = '{"em": "test@test.com"}', field = '{"_id": 1}')
```

Answer (score 11):

I realise this is an old question and OP has probably figured it out by now, but I think the answer should be

```
mongoOBj <- m$find(query = '{"em": "test@test.com"}', field = '{}')
```

instead of

```
mongoOBj <- m$find(query = '{"em": "test@test.com"}', field = '{"_id": 1}')
```

In the second case, the result will be a data frame containing ONLY the IDs. The first line will result in a data frame containing the queried data, including the IDs.

By default, `field = '{"_id": 0}'`, meaning _id is not part of the output.

Answer (score 1):

FYI So the easiest way to get all fields is to do the query with field="{}". That will overwrite the default in the mongolite:: package find() arguments list.

It was driving me nuts for a little while too.